# optimize jquery prev selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to make the selector below better?
Without adding extra classes or id's?
Only select the first `item-2` counted from `item-5` downwards.
This works, but there has to be an easier way.

`$first_previous = $($('li.item-5').prevAll('.item-2')[0]);`

```
<ul>
   <li class="item-1">list item 1</li>
   <li class="item-2">Unkown number of item-2 will happen</li>
   <li class="item-2">Unkown number of item-2 will happen</li>
   <li class="item-2">list item 2 Only select this one, not the other #2</li>
   <li class="item-3">list item 3</li>
   <li class="item-4">list item 4</li>
   <li class="item-5">list item 5 Start here</li>
   <li class="item-2">it might even occur after the item-5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have to work backwards? Why not the last in the item-2 selection?

Comment: I've updated my question. It might happen even after `item-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
$(this).siblings('.item-2').eq(1);
```

(Where `$(this)` is a jQuery object containing an element with a class of `.item-5`)

But you will want to use something like http://jsperf.com/ to find out which way is quicker !

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHPEM/)

### Update

Then try this :

```
$(this).siblings('.item-2').last();
```

Docs for [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

OK ... then try :

```
$(this).prev('.item-2')
```

Uses[`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

### Update 2

Loop the items and get the first which will be the one you want :

```
$('.item-5').prevAll().each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('item-2')) {
        alert($(this).text());
        return false; // break early
    }
});​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7FX/)

Comment: I didn't read it correct last night. I won't know for sure how many `item-2` elements there will be. So this one won't work. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: that's not helping either:( in my updated answer I show that number 2 also can happen AFTER #5 this way you will select that one

Comment: that won't work because `prev` only selects the first previous element and matches that against the given selector. But the first previous is #4 (and #3). I already tried it. It's a nifty one right ;)

Comment: It works, not sure if it's better then my monster selector. But I'm accepting the answer. It seams this one isn't simple to select. thx for the support